# How to properly check if input data from JSON is double?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to find a proper way to check during runtime, if input data is double.
Let's use this code as example:

```
List<dynamic> data = [
  {"lat": 47.480088391416935, "lng": -16.237792798261637},
  , 
];

double calc( double lat2, double long2 ){
  double lat1 = 48.68370745897208;
  double long1 = -27.048339622524924;
  double p = 0.017453292519943295;
  double distance = 0.0
  double res = 0.0;
    try {
      res = 0.5 -
          cos((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
          cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - cos((long2 - long1) * p)) / 2;
      return distance = 12742 * asin(sqrt(res));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return 0.0;
    }
  }
```

When I specify function arguments like this:

```
double calc(double lat2, double long2) {
}
```

Then I have protection when calling the function `calc` with wrong type argument:
for example, String:

`print(calc(47.480088391416935,"-16.237792798261637"));`

But runtime type checks inside calc(), which validate that lat and long are double, don't work:

`if (value is! double)` or `if (value.runtimeType != double)`

```
List<dynamic> data = [
  {"lat": 47.480088391416935, "lng": -16.237792798261637},
  , 
];

double calc( double lat2, double long2 ){
  double lat1 = 48.68370745897208;
  double long1 = -27.048339622524924;
  // input validation #1
  if (lat2 is! double || long2 is! double){
    return 0.0;
  }
  // input validation #2
  if (value.runtimeType != double || value.runtimeType != double){
    return 0.0;
  }
  double p = 0.017453292519943295;
  double distance = 0.0
  double res = 0.0;
    try {
      res = 0.5 -
          cos((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
          cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - cos((long2 - long1) * p)) / 2;
      return distance = 12742 * asin(sqrt(res));
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return 0.0;
    }
  }
```

Both (#1 & #2) return false when I use: `double calc( double lat2, double long2 )`.

When I use dynamic type:

```
double calc(lat2, lon2){
}
```

Runtime type checks work, but there are no checks when calling the function `calc(lat2, lon2)`:

```
// no warning in this case
print(calc(47.480088391416935,"-16.237792798261637"));
```

So, the question is - what is best solution to have both checks: type checks for arguments when calling the function and type checks inside the function during runtime.

And, btw, why `try catch` is silent when we have `cos((lat2 - lat1)` and wrong input like this:
`print(calc(47.480088391416935,"-16.237792798261637"));`

***UPD***
I want to move all exception handling concerning types to calc() function, so there is no need to do in all the places where calc() is called:

```
try {
   print(calc(47.480088391416935,-16.237792798261637));
} catch (e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, lets create couple of methods to check if we can get a double from a string,, or it cant and handle everything in one method to be called

```
class DoubleFromStringTest {

  /// lets just make a method that takes dynamic and returns double
  /// and it should process the strings and doubles
  static double getDoubleIfPossible(dynamic input){
    double _output;

    print('starting : getDoubleIfPossible : input : ${input}');
    print('starting : getDoubleIfPossible : input.runtimeType : ${input.runtimeType}');

    /// some safety layer first
    if (input != null){

      /// when its already a double,, we are good
      if (input.runtimeType == double){

        _output = input;
      }

      /// when its a string
      else if (input.runtimeType == String){

        /// we need to make sure that it's a double inside a string,, and not a combination of doubles & characters in one string like '15X8wS'
        /// so lets do an another method and call it here
        bool _inputIsDoubleInsideAString = _objectIsDoubleInString(input);

        if (_inputIsDoubleInsideAString == true){

          /// so its a double inside a string,, then we can get the double now without firing an error
          _output = _stringToDouble(input);

        }

        // else {
        //   /// input is not a double in a string
        //   /// will do nothing,, and the _output shall return null
        //   /// so I will comment these unnecessary lines
        // }


      }

      // /// it not a string and its not a double
      // else {
      //   /// do nothing and return null
      //   /// so I will comment these unnecessary lines
      // }

    }

    return _output;
  }

  static bool _objectIsDoubleInString(dynamic string) {

    bool _objectIsDoubleInString;
    double _double;

    if (string != null){
      _double = double.tryParse(string.trim());
    }

    if (_double == null){
      _objectIsDoubleInString = false;
    } else {
      _objectIsDoubleInString = true;
    }

    print('objectIsDoubleInString : _double is : $_double');

    return _objectIsDoubleInString;

  }

  static double _stringToDouble(String string){
    double _value;

    if (string != null){
      _value = double.parse(string);
    }

    return _value;
  }

}
```

then lets make a method test and see if this works

```
 test("testing double from a string", () async {

    String _inputA = '34.55';
    double _output = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(_inputA);
    expect(_output, 34.55);

    String _inputB = 'XX34.55';
    double _outputB = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(_inputB);
    expect(_outputB, null);

    String _inputC = 'XAfdjdb4';
    double _outputC = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(_inputC);
    expect(_outputC, null);

    String _inputD = '178712364871624.83762874623';
    double _outputD = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(_inputD);
    expect(_outputD, 178712364871624.83762874623);

  });
```

then use this method either before the calc(double a, double b)

of have it inside the

```
calc(dynamic a, dynami b){
  final double _a = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(a);
  final double _b = DoubleFromStringTest.getDoubleIfPossible(b);

// do things ...
    }
```

**works like a charm**

Comment: Thanks! The initial idea is to have both checks at the same time: during compilation and runtime. Compilation time checks for input data require that function arguments are not dynamic, so dart checks it by itself that we are using the right data for arguments... For sure, it's over complicated, but I was curious if it's possible to have both checks done in elegant way.